# Do JavaScript interpreters set all variables to undefined

Tags: javascript, interpreter

When creating a variable such as `var three = 3;` do JavaScript interpreters first assign `var three;` then `three = 3;` or is it done all in one shot?

The part that is of interest to me here is the potential intermediate `undefined` value and a way, if possible to observe that process.

### Edit

**New Title:** Does variable declaration happen before variable initialization

Given this one line JavaScript File

```
var three  = 3;
```

Does the interpreter still hoist the variable three and effectively change this to

```
var three;
three = 3;
```

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) has a good article explaining this in some detail.

Comment: there are many javascript engines, which engine or platform do you ask for?

Comment: I'm most interested in Chrome's V8 but I was hoping the answer would be nearly universal.

Comment: @fardjad's answer is universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All JavaScript variables are hoisted, as @fardjad mentioned.  They are also initially set to be `undefined`.

To show this, consider the following:

```js
var a= eval('thr'+'ee');
var three= 3;

console.log(a);      //undefined
console.log(three);  //3
```

This is the equivalent to this:

```js
var a;
var three;

a= eval('thr'+'ee');
three= 3;

console.log(a);      //undefined
console.log(three);  //3
```

No JavaScript interpreter to my knowledge would be smart enough to realize that the `three` variable isn't needed before it's declared and initialized.  If it *weren't* hoisted, the `eval` code would throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript interpreters [hoist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) the variables before code execution, so writing:

```
console.log(three);
var three = 3;
```

is effectively the same as:

```
var three;
console.log(three);
three = 3;
```

Comment: But do the interpreters hoist variables (assign undefined before the actual value) that don't need to be hoisted (e.g. they're defined on the first line of a scope)? It would sound horribly inefficient to do so.

Comment: I could not have put that better @Juhana and this is the essence of my question. In either case, I'm really looking for a way to prove/capture this. Any browser/environment will do.

Comment: A variable can't be hoisted unless the code has at least first been fully parsed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is done in several stages as the JavaScript is optimized before execution, and to do that the engine must have some understanding of the code. Here's a picture of how the engine handles JavaScript specifically for chromium taken from http://blog.chromium.org/2015/03/new-javascript-techniques-for-rapid.html:

[image]

You can see by this that the code is both parsed (to check for validity) and probably to create lexical tokens that is then compiled and optimized before runtime execution. It's during this compile stage that the variables will be declared (giving the affect of hoisting) yet during the execution where they'll be initialized.

I've been watching an [Advanced JavaScript](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/advanced-javascript) course taught by Kyle Simpson that talks a lot about this and discusses a 2 phase way of compiling JavaScript and dealing with variable hoisting. Here is a modified example from the course that doesn't use `eval` to make it simpler:

```js
console.log(a);

var a = 2;
console.log(a);

console.log(c);
```

What you can see here is that `a` is successfully logged as undefined at the start - before they have been declared. This is due to variable hoisting as mentioned in other answers were the output of the parsing engine is to treat it more like:

```
var a;
console.log(a);

a = 2;
console.log(a);
```

Due to the fact that the compiler has defined `a` before execution time, we're able to log their `undefined` values, something that you couldn't do if they were simply defined and initialized at the same time.

This doesn't work with `c` however as it wasn't defined and you'll get a `ReferenceError`. The reason for highlighting that, is that this is the same sort of error you'd expect if `a` wasn't hoisted to the top and defined before the initial `console.log(a);`.

[image]

Comment: I thought so too, is there any way to observe/prove this?

Comment: @jeanpier_rw I doubt it, each engine will be slightly different. Trying to find the video I'm currently watching about this, the presenter may be able to help answer your question

Comment: Android app keeps crashing trying to update answer. Here is a course in watching about this sort of thing http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/advanced-javascript

Comment: @jeanpier_re no problem, hopefully my edits help demonstrate this too explaining why it works like this.